# Add css transition on svg element class changing

Tags: css-transitions, jointjs

I'm exploring the `markAvailable` property of [this](http://jointjs.com/tutorial/ports#markAvailable) example.
I would like to add a transition while the ports color change.
So I changed the css as follow:

```
/* port styling */
.available-magnet{
   fill: yellow;
   transition: fill 0.5s;
}

.port circle{
   transition: fill 0.5s;
}
```

But I still do not get any transition.

**UPDATE**

I created an [example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OMgNzX). It is clear that the problem is inside *defaultLink* property. In particular, removing the *z* attribute I get the right transition, but in this way I lost a fundamental property for my need, that is indeed to have all links with the lower z index.

Comment: Can you post an example of your code not working ?

Comment: @vals please have a look to the update

Answer (score 1):

The Example reported in the Update is correct.
In order to maintain each link on the back of other elements (that corresponds to set a z value equals to -1), Simply use the method [`link.toBack()`](http://www.jointjs.com/api#joint.dia.Link:toBack) each time a new link is created. In this way the transitions work.

Answer (score 0):

Use -webkit-transition if you are in Chrome if you are in Mozilla use -moz-transition

Comment: I already tried but nothing changed, the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: It is the one present in the example [link](http://jointjs.com/tutorial/ports#markAvailable)